# Realtek AC97 Audio and Microsoft Audio

Tags: audio

I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate on my laptop and have recently installed Realtek AC97 Audio drivers on it. But, it doesn't show up in Device Manager anywhere, nor anywhere else. Additionally, Microsoft High Definition Audio Device keeps re-installing itself whenever I turn on my computer. Might there be some backdoor on my computer? What else might be causing this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment yet...

Have you tried removing all Realtek software from your computer, rebooting, and seeing if Windows will just install the audio devices itself? The drivers/software might just be messed up, but it doesn't sound like a security risk or anything of that nature.

Comment: Yes. I have removed the Realtek drivers and re-booted but it still doesn't work and the Microsoft driver takes over EVERY TIME.